# Slide Left/Right effect on a Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I have an Activity, on which i am displaying a Question.
There are Previous, Next buttons on this screen.

Every time a user presses Previous/Next - a different question is displayed.
Now i want a sliding (right left) affect on this view when Previous/Next buttons are pressed(Activity remains same) .

I can do the sliding affect with Transitions across Activities(from one Activity view to another) like this:

```
...
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim1, R.anim.anim2);
...
```

But how do i give that affect on a single activity?

Comment: Is each question a relative layout or is it a list view or what is it?

Comment: a fragments inside a viewpager

Answer (score 1):

Definately you can do it using ViewPager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Here is a [Link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/04/example-of-viewpager-with-custom.html) of a pretty neat example for your need.

I will explain it for you

Here is main activity layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.androidviewpagerapp.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You MainActivity should be something like this

```
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ViewPager viewPager;
 MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
  myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
  viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

 }

 private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

  int NumberOfPages = 5;

  int[] res = { 
   android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_compass,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_directions,
   android.R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery};
  int[] backgroundcolor = { 
   0xFF101010,
   0xFF202020,
   0xFF303030,
   0xFF404040,
   0xFF505050};

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return NumberOfPages;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
   return view == object;
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


  TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
  textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  textView.setTextSize(30);
  textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
  textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));

  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
  imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
  LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

  LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
  layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
  LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
  layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolor[position]);
  layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  layout.addView(textView);
  layout.addView(imageView);

  final int page = position;
  layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
  "Page " + page + " clicked", 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}});

  container.addView(layout);
  return layout;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)     {
   container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
  }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) + [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and listen onClick of Next and Prev buttons to manually [scroll the pages](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) in view pager.